# Unittest Subprocess ValueErorr: embedded null byte Python 3

Tags: python, unit-testing, subprocess, pickle

I'm writing unit tests for a process that executes a python snippet. The unit test is passing in python 2, but failing in python 3. The unit test is as follows:

```
def test_exec_snippet_subprocess(self):
    snip_string = 'result = {"success": True}'
    
    snippet = pickle.dumps((snip_string, None))

    _process = subprocess.Popen(
        ["python", "-m", "snippet_execution", snippet],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )

    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
        _read_process_stdout = _process.stdout.read
    else:
        _read_process_stdout = _process.stdout.buffer.read
    snippet_result = ""
    
    data = _read_process_stdout().strip()
    if len(data) > 0:
        snippet_result = snippet_result + data

    snippet_result = pickle.loads(snippet_result)
    self.assertTrue(
        self.snippet_result["success"],
    )
```

and the portion of `snippet_execution.py` file that is causing the issue looks like:

```
import sys
import pickle
serialize = pickle.dumps
deserialize = pickle.loads

def execute_serialized_snippet(serialized_snippet):
    with RedirectedStandardIO(StringIO(), StringIO()):
        success, results = execute_snippet(*deserialize(serialized_snippet))
        print(serialize(results, protocol=2))
        return success, serialize(
            results, protocol=2
        )  # `procotcol = 2` ensures pickled object is readable in Python 2

if sys.version_info.major == 2:
    print(results)  # Dump to stdout for Python 2
else:
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(results)  # Write a unicode object to buffer for Python 3
```

What is causing the error I get when my unit test runs in python 3?

```
tests/test_exec_snippet.py F........                                     [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_________________ TestExecSnippet.test_exec_snippet_subprocess _________________
tests/test_exec_snippet.py:94: in test_exec_snippet_subprocess
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:800: in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:1482: in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
E   ValueError: embedded null byte
```

I discovered that the pickling process is creating null bytes.

`b'\x80\x02X\x1e\x00\x00\x00result = {"success": True}q\x00N\x86q\x01.'`

But if I take them out using `.replace(b'\x00',b'')`, then my pickled object says it is truncated and can't be unpickled.

Comment: Why are you accessing the buffer in Python 3? Just use `self._process.stdout.read()` regardless of which version of Python you are using. (There's also probably no reason for `_process` to be an instance attribute; you don't want to share it between multiple tests, do you?)

Comment: I've removed the instance attribute. However, just running `_process.stdout.read()` still results in the same issue. The reason that the buffer was being used was it is required to execute a python 3 snippet from a python 2 process.